# How to ensure that article manager use specified values for custom article fields?

Tags: validation, record-type, articles, required-field

How do I ensure that the article manager uses specified values for custom article fields? Which of the following options I should implement?

1. validation rules on article object
2. Make fields required on page layout
3. Use field dependencies on article types
4. Create different article types for different requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a validation rule can very easily have the effect of making a field a required field. If that's going to happen, it's a good practice to mark the field as required in the page layout so a user knows they need to complete the field before they try to save the record. That will make your pages more "user friendly".

Using Types has it's pros and cons. If you have a LOT of different categories of articles that you want to be able to distinguish, then creating Types for the major ones can be advantageous for organizing them. If the Type corresponds to a Record Type, it will also allow you to create Object Specific Actions that will pre-fill the values in certain fields associated with the Record Type when creating a new record. That could be very advantageous if you have clearly defined types of articles that are easy for your users to identify.

I don't think there's one specific option you should implement, but instead a judicious combination of them would be more appropriate, all of which would depend on your specific org and the articles that you're dealing with.